# Google Chrome Windows Desktop Organization in Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome

When closing google chrome browser on OSX I often find myself losing my carefully ordered window placement between my many desktops. All the chrome windows get bundled in the same desktop whenever chrome restarts.

Is there anyway to get Chrome to remember the placement of all the in OSX Desktops after restarting Chrome.

Thank You for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no it's not possible.

macOS will only 'remember' a single Space for any app. If you move windows to different Spaces, on next launch they will all migrate to the first available Space.

Someone, somewhere, may have made a utility to do this for you - but I've never found one.

The only usable solution I have ever found is to duplicate the app & change the bundle identifier - then each instance could be remembered separately.
See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105474/85275 for a way to do this on Safari.